# Why is my iframe causing the rest of the page to go blank?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make an iframe that embeds on any web page where it only shows up as a button on the bottom right of a webpage and when clicked open an about 100px by 100px box that is also embeded on the web page in the bottom right corner. The issue is that every time I put the iframe on the page, the middle of the page where their was content before goes blank. Here is the code for the iframe:

```
    <iframe src="ka.html" title="KA"
    style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px"
    height="100%" width="100%">
    </iframe>
```

I've tried editing the style but I'm not sure that the style is the problem. The iframe uses an html file and js code. I could use some help in figuring out where the problem is coming from and how I can fix it. I really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: put the code in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style *is* the cause, if I’ve understood your description of the problem.

The combination of `position: absolute`  and zero for top/left/bottom/right will cause the iFrame to cover the first ancestor element that has `position: relative` (or the body element if there is none).

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any advice as to what I should change? As the only way I could think of getting the placement correct is to use position absolute.

Comment: If as you say you just want the iFrame to appear in the bottom right and be a certain width then something like `bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px` might do the trick. Be aware that anything the iFrame covers won’t be clickable/interactable, even if you make the background of your iFrame transparent.

Comment: I tried the code you included but I keep getting the placement of the iframe in the top left corner, instead of the intended the bottom right. I don't want to over reach but do you know of any ways to get the iframe such that it doesn't effect the rest of the page and stay on the bottom right?